# Output file names in folder to text file using batch

Tags: batch-file

I would like to run a batch script to output new or modified file names within the past 24 hours to a text document, recursively. Please advise!

Comment: forfiles might do the trick. I've used this before. Any examples for the proposed question?

Comment: forfiles (and also xcopy (xcopy is even better than forfiles)) will work only with "today - x days". This is fine, if you want files e.g. "today and yesterday", but won't work, if you want "now - 24 hours"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a vbscript file to do this.

Use the filesystemobject to [get file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sheydkke%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) information.  Then check if the [datecreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6a7czx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) or [datelastmodified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xh895w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) values are less than a day old, by checking if the returned value minus [now](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_now.asp) is less than 1.  Then use the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to write the file names to a text file if they are new or newly modified.

Code:

```
Dim objFS, objOutput, objFolder, objFile, objTS, strListFilePath, strFolderToCheck

strListFilePath = "C:\NewFilesList.txt" ' or whatever
strFolderToCheck = "C:\" ' or whatever
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolderToCheck)
objFS.CreateTextFile strListFilePath
Set objOutput = objFS.GetFile(strListFilePath)
Set objTS = objOutput.OpenAsTextStream(2, -2) 'This means open for writing and use the default tristate value
CheckFolder(objFolder)
objTS.Close

Set objFS = Nothing
Set outFolder = Nothing
Set objOutput = Nothing
Set objTS = Nothing

Sub CheckFolder(objThisFolder)

    Dim objSubFolder
    for each objSubFolder in objThisFolder.SubFolders
        CheckFolder(objSubFolder)
    next
    for each objFile in objThisFolder.Files
        if (Now - objFile.DateCreated & vbCrLf < 1) or (Now - objFile.DateLastModified < 1) then
            'Less than 24hrs old
            objTS.WriteLine(objFile.path)
        end if
    next    
End Sub
```

Comment: I have limited knowledge. I will accept this answer if you can provide an example for my case.

Comment: Awesome! This is wonderful. I will test now and reply back shortly :)

Comment: @Snipper: I just realized I had the inequality operators backwards.  It would list files over a day, not under.  I just fixed that too.

Comment: Oops, change that to CheckFolder also.  I copy pasted this from my script and changed that function name after I did.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your help with this and it will go a long way!

Answer (score 1):

This should provide a list - c:\aaa does not exist and is meant to be there.
Change c:\files to your source folder and alter the date to suit.

```
xcopy /s/h/e/k/f/c/l /d:04-28-2013 "c:\files" c:\aaa\  >file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. This will work but the date needs to be dynamic, 24 hours from current date. Can xcopy pull all files 24 hours from current date?